# Autofill Random Text from defined - Firefox Addon

Tags: autofill

I'm using Autofill addon `https://addons.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/addon/autofill-262804/` and I want to fill my text field with random text from definied.
For example I want to fill `/* City */ city|town` field with one of the definied: `London, Paris, Amsterdam`

But I dont know how to do that.

The developer says:

> Variables – use special variables to output random words (text spinner), numbers, and alphanumeric characters

So it is possible.

Please help me.

## edit

or maybe do you know any addon/method to autofill field with random text from definied

Comment: I've got the solution. It works with Chrome fine. Write the words like that: `{word1|word2|...}`

Answer (score 2):

Despite putting a bounty on your question, I've managed to find the solution - I too had trouble finding it in the Google Groups pages and the dev's site, until I found his ["other" page](http://www.tohodo.com/autofill/help-firefox.html#other), which states:

Expand variables – If this box is checked, {...} will be replaced with the variable's output. There are currently three types of variables you can use:

```
{word1|word2|...} – This variable acts like a text spinner, randomly outputting one word from a list of words that you specify. Example: to output "house", "condo", "apartment", or "flat", you would enter {house|condo|apartment|flat}
{#} or {#number} – This variable outputs a random number. You can specify the number of digits after # ({#1} is equivalent to {#}). Example: to generate a random telephone number, you would enter ({#3}) {#3}-{#4}
{$} or {$number} – This variable outputs a random alphanumeric string. You can specify the number of characters after $ ({$1} is equivalent to {$}). Example: to generate a 16-character dummy text string, you would enter {$16}
```

So for example, in the value to autofill box for your element, putting:

```
{$6}@{$6}.com
```

would insert an email address of 6 random letters, followed by an @, then six random letters, followed by a .com.

Answer (score 0):

Value to Autofill should be :

```
    {London|Paris|Amsterdam}
```